# ¿"Los auriculares" o "el auriculares"?

Tags: plurales, sustantivos

¿Cuando hablo sobre un par de auriculares en español, cuál es correcto?

> Los auriculares fueron caro.
>
> El auriculares fue caro.

¿Y también, es *auriculares* la palabra correcta para esta cosa?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way is `Los auriculares` Because it is the plural form of the word, the singular form would be `el auricular`.

Also `auriculares` is a valid word, but for me (I'm from Mexico) it feels more natural to say `(los) audifonos`.

Something important to clarify is that seeing how `auriculares` is a plural word, and since it could cause confusion, think of it as something similar to `pantalones` (there's only one item, but it's the right word to use). I guess the easiest way to understand it is that each side of the item is an `auricular`, so we could say you have an `auricular` on each ear when you use your headset, and you're using/wearing `auriculares` as a whole.

**EXTRA**

For the sake of improving your Spanish, I have a few tips...

First, the right overall expression would be:

> Los auriculares (or audifonos if you want) fueron caros.

Note the right word for expensive here is `caros` (plural form) and not `caro` (singular form) for the reason I explained before.

Finally your questions are:

> ¿Cuando hablando sobre un par de auriculares en español, cuál es correcto?

which is the wrong way to ask. You could do it in the following ways instead:

- ¿Cuando hablamos sobre un par de auriculares en español, cuál es la expresion correcta?
- Hablando sobre un par de auriculares en español, ¿Qué es lo correcto?

And your other question:

> ¿Y también, es auriculares el palabra correcto por esa cosa?

That one is also incorrect, `palabra` is a feminine word, so instead of saying `el palabra` you have to say `la palabra`; the same is true for `correcto` which should be `correcta`. And `por` should be `para`. So your question should be:

> ¿Y también, es auriculares la palabra correcta para esa cosa?

I'd personally use `esta` instead of `esa` as you were talking about that item just before...

Comment: Thank you very much! Your corrections make sense, I appreciate them :) About *los auriuculares* vs *el auricular*, though... Does that mean that for one pair of headphones, that's *el auricular* (or *el audifono*)? And *los auriculares* means multiple pairs of headphones? (I was confused on this one because in English, *headphones* is both singular and plural. "Those are nice headphones." (1 set) "I bought a lot of headphones today." (more than 1 set)

Comment: @WendiKidd see my updated answer :) also, I'd say auriculares/audifonos is valid for both 1 set and multiple sets of headphones...

Comment: @Theta30 indeed, thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: I just wanted to add that in Spain we would indeed use *auriculares* rather than *audífonos* (*audífonos* would be what the hearing-impaired people use). Regional variations aside, I think this answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Another small correction: "¿Y también, es auriculares la palabra correcta para esa cosa?" should be "Y también: ¿es auriculares ...?"